# React components not displaying in laravel-mix react project deployed on the share hosting server

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I was trying to deploy laravel mix react project on the share hosting server Hostinger. And it actually worked with the serer loading the index file correctly. But the react components inside the laravel blade files are not displaying. I also checked the network and it seems that the js file of the react component is not being returned from the server.

The react components which are rendered in js files connected to the blade all run fine locally. When I run yarn watch command on local project it shows that all js files run fine. But the server project will not render them. I also ran commands like "yarn prod" and "php artisan config:cache" before deploying. I am not sure why the react components will not render on server.

webpack.mix.js

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel applications. By default, we are compiling the CSS
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/js/articleCreate.js', 'public/js').react();
mix.js('resources/js/articleLike.js', 'public/js').react();
mix.js('resources/js/statistics.js', 'public/js').react();
```

Comment: Are there errors in the browser console? Are there errors in your Laravel log file? Are there errors in your server logs?

Comment: I just found out that I have to add public in front of the file being requested. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out I just need to add public/ in front of the js file being requested where react component is linked.